# Unable to resolve "Celery Result backend. DisabledBackend object has no attribute _get_task_meta_for"

Tags: python, celery

I am building a small Flask application that calls the get completion API from OpenAI to fetch some information. I want to run these API calls in the background (partially because Heroku has a 30 sec. timeout). I tried with redis, and now with Celery, but even though the background task is created and executed correctly, I can't seem to resolve the "Celery Result backend. DisabledBackend object has no attribute _get_task_meta_for" error.

I've checked the various issues on SF, used Chat GPT Plus, and looked at various App Factory blogs.

Previously I used Postgres and even though the celery table is successfully created during database creation check, the error won't go away.

I have set up the celery_config.py in two different ways - of course I uncomment one before running :-) not working on both:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
#option1 CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "db+postgresql://user:pwd@localhost/db"
#option2 CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://localhost:6379/0"
```

celery_utils.py:

```
from celery import Celery
celery = Celery("website", broker="", backend="")
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config["CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND"],
        broker=app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"],
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    return celery
```

tasks.py:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def fetchContextualNote_async(self, term, context):
// logic here
```

celery logs:When I run

```
celery -A appname.tasks worker --loglevel=info
```

I can see the API call and successful execution.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the backend does not get set.

I can't really figure it out from

`celery = Celery(..., backend="")` and `make_celery`.

Best bet is to look at your Celery worker startup screen and see if the results property is set to your backend url:

```
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         tasks:0x104b1f250
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/0
```

Comment: I've mentioned the app and result backend, but for something's wrong with the set up. This is what I see in the worker start-up screen... let me check it again

celery@Vamsis-MacBook-Pro.local v5.3.4 (emerald-rush)
macOS-13.6-x86_64-i386-64bit 2023-10-11 13:42:00
[config]
app:         website:0x1116e3b50
transport:   amqp://guest:**@localhost:5672//
results:     disabled://
concurrency: 8 (prefork)
task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
[queues]
celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery

Comment: --updated -- 
[config]
app:         website:0x10fccfb10
transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
results:     postgresql://postgres:**@localhost/tisitv0
concurrency: 8 (prefork)
task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
[queues]
celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


I've confirmed that the database exists. The task goes onto pending status, and then returns to Success. However, my main process throws an expectation as soon as the task is created. Not sure how to retrieve the results of the task